# How do you know if a decentralized solar PV is connected in series or in parallel?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy

[image]

I'm using a decentralized solar PV system(4 nos). I want to know that are they connected in series or in parallel ?

The output current of each of my converter connected to solar panel is 4.4A. So will the current be added up or be the same ?

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: How can i draw a schematic here?can i upload any files?

Comment: In the editor next to the "Add Image" function is a schematic editor.

Comment: Block diagram is better than nothing but it's no circuit diagram. Use the circuit function and draw one in your original question.